# What is the weakpoint of PRNG based encryption?

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator

Let's say I used this encryption schema:

[image: Schema]

In words instead of images:

1. Hash the encryption key with SHA256
2. Split it in half, first half use as XOR key for first 128 bit block of plaintext
3. Hash the second half from previous step with SHA256
4. Carry the hash to point 2), rinse, repeat.

What are potential problems/weakpoints of such encryption algorithm?

Comment: say you have encrypted a 14GB hd video file and send it to someone, how easy and quick would it be to seek to 80% ?

Comment: It's a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher#Security), so predictable edits to cleartext can be performed by editing the ciphertext directly.

Comment: @RichieFrame The same could be said for AES in PCBC mode, that's not cryptographical weakness.

Comment: @KryštofVosyka I did not say it was a cryptographical weakness.. but it surely is a usability weakness

Comment: If you need to use a hash for a CSPRNG, why can't you just feed it with a key concatenated with a counter? It won't be as efficient as a CTR-based generator with a fast block cipher, but it'll be better than this. That way you won't risk hitting a short cycle, and you can seek anywhere into the keystream.

Comment: If you squint a little bit this looks very much like a [sponge construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function) variant, a sort of keyed sponge in "overwrite" mode (see [this paper](https://keccak.team/files/CSF-0.1.pdf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a stream cipher I don't think there is any direct way to break the cipher.

First of all, it is extremely inefficient, as Richie already mentions. SHA-256 has an input block size of 512 bits, and you're only propagating 128 out of 256 output bits. So you're wasting a lot of input space. In other words, it won't be twice as slow as just SHA-256 due to the limited output being used, it will be about 8 times as slow (!).

One of the problems with your algorithm is that it only propagates 128 bits out of the internal state of the 256 bit internal state of SHA-256. That means that you are more likely to hit a cycle within the hash function. Probably your cipher mode has limited input size because of that. It is probably similar in security to CBC for a normal 128 bit block cipher in that way.

A bit of a unfair problem with it is that it has not received any formal review and that it doesn't have a formal proof. As for practical problems, a hash function input is generally not designed to take any keys, so you need to be aware of that. SHA-256 is fortunately relatively resistant against side channel attacks by itself. One good thing is that the key is not repeated anywhere in the followup hash calls.

As a cipher mode your algorithm is *deterministic* as it doesn't take an IV. It would however be easy to add a 128 bit IV or (rather) nonce at the start, simply as additional input next to the key. As it stands, it cannot be used as a cipher for repeated messages. You might mitigate the cycle issues by adding a counter to each invocation of SHA-256 as well, there is space enough for another 128 bit value.

Comment: This should not be seen as a full review; not that those kind of reviews are off topic here. However, for such a simple construction we sometimes do explain some obvious issues with it. Beware that I might change my mind if this leads to extended discussions.

Comment: Even if it hasn't received formal review, I'd think a proof would be rather trivial to come up with under the assumption that SHA-256 is indistinguishable from a random function. But honestly, I'd be surprised if there isn't any research into truncated hash functions put in an OFB-like mode (there is for HMAC, at least).

Comment: The construction from the question is a standard PRG extender, so if we model SHA256 as a PRG for short inputs, the entire thing is a PRG again. So it's a secure "one-time-stream-cipher".